# Finding indexes where substring is present

Tags: c

So right now my code checks if the sub string is present in the code and returns true or false, I would like to find where these substrings are located in the total string. how can you implement that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool checksub(const char *strng,const char *subs){
  if (*strng=='\0' && *subs!='\0'){
    return false;
  }
  if (*subs=='\0'){
    return true;}
  if (*strng==*subs){
    return checksub(strng+1,subs+1);
  }
  return false;
}
bool lsub(char *strng,char *subs){
  if (*strng=='\0'){
    return false;
  }
  if (*strng==*subs){
    if (checksub(strng,subs)){
      return 1;
    }
  }
  return lsub(strng+1,subs);
}

int main(){
  
  printf("%d\n",checksub("ababuu","ab"));
  printf("%d\n",checksub("the bed bug bites","bit"));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to accomplish your goal?

Comment: Also, some comments on style: Your arguments should be `const char *`, since you're not modifying the strings. Accidentally modifying you strings could lead to unexpected results and, since you pass in pointers to string literals, to undefined behaviour. You're also returning `1`, instead of `true` in one spot. While this isn't incorrect, it's confusing. The `else` branch in `lsub` is also an unnecessary duplicate of what immediately follows.

Comment: This last point is much more opinion-based, and there are very valid reasons to disagree, but I'd also generally prefer `'\0'` to `0`. This makes it clear that you mean a string `NUL` terminator, not the value 0 being interpreted as just an integer number. I'm not suggesting that you should change what you do, but I do want to make sure that you're aware that `'\0'` exists.

Comment: @thomas jager like this

Comment: I just wanted to print the index of the sub strings once their presence was confirmed

Comment: So I guess you're not allowed to just use the standard library's `strstr()`?

Comment: I wasn't necessarily suggesting that you apply all those things immediately to what you show, just to point out some things that might help you write better code. Also, one important thing is to be consistent. With your edit, you now have a mix of what you had before and what I suggested.

Comment: If your function is supposed to return the index of the substring when the substring is in fact present, then what is it supposed to return when the substring is *not* present?

Comment: @thomas jager you do realize that you are just pointing out slight overlooks in the code which does not provide any info as to how to move forward, while I do appreciate your points which might be useful later on, is it really helping out with the answer?

Comment: @Light I've stated earlier on my problem with the question, being that you haven't shown an attempt to actually do what you're trying to do.

Comment: @John bollinger thank you also when the function returns zero

Comment: I think I have to start this code over thanks for your help

Comment: Ok, @Light, the function certainly *can* return 0 when the substring is not found, but do note that that does not provide for distinguishing between the "not found" case and the "found at the beginning" case.

Comment: @john I see  what you mean

Comment: I think you've given us a bit of a red herring.  Your `main()` program demonstrates the `checksub()` function, but it's the `lsub()` function that finds a test string within a target string.  `checksub` tests only whether the target string *starts with* the test string.  I think you could convert `lsub()` to return the index of the substring instead of simply a `bool` indicating whether it is present.  On the other hand, I would write this completely differently, without recursion.

Answer (score 0):

First you should get rid of recursion since it's often slow and dangerous, for nothing gained.

A (naive) version of `strstr` that returns an index rather than a pointer might look like this:

```
int strstr_index (const char* original, const char* sub)
{
  int index = -1;

  for(const char* str=original; *str!='\0' && index==-1; str++)
  {
    for(size_t i=0; str[i]==sub[i] && str[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
      if(sub[i+1] == '\0')
      {
        index = (int)(str - original);
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return index;
}
```

This returns -1 if not found, otherwise an index.

- It iterates across the string one character at a time.
- When a character match with the sub string is found, it starts executing the inner loop as well.
- If the inner loop continues to find matches all the way to the end of the sub string, then we found a match.
- The index can be obtained by pointer arithmetic: the start address of the found sub string minus the start of the string. The result of that subtraction is strictly speaking a special integer type called `ptrdiff_t`, but I used `int` to simplify the example.